# ElasticSearch cluster eventually starts returning wrong hits.total on search

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a cluster running version 5.6.16. It has ~5.7k primary shards, ~2k indices and 28 nodes (3 masters, 3 coordinators and 22 data nodes):

```
{
  "cluster_name": "foo",
  "status": "green",
  "timed_out": false,
  "number_of_nodes": 28,
  "number_of_data_nodes": 22,
  "active_primary_shards": 5778,
  "active_shards": 11556,
  "relocating_shards": 0,
  "initializing_shards": 0,
  "unassigned_shards": 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis": 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number": 100
}
```

Eventually, whatever search we do in some indices return an insanely high doc count, even when no results are found.

For instance:

```
curl -s 'http://localhost:9200/*/_search?q=nope:thiswillneverexist&terminate_after=1' | jq -r '.'
{
  "took": 871,
  "timed_out": false,
  "terminated_early": false,
  "num_reduce_phases": 12,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5778,
    "successful": 5778,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 9787770,
    "max_score": 2,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

I couldn't find anything in the logs or any correlation with anything else, nor any other issues/foruns/etc (maybe I don't know what to search for exactly).

The only workaround we found so far is to restart the cluster.

Has anyone seen something like this? Any ideas on what I should investigate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really strange and in order to debug the issue, I would do the below:

1. Why inner hits array is empty, elasticsearch by default returns 10 matching docs in the inner hits array which would include `index-name` and `document-id` which would be very helpful to see if that `index`, and `doc` contains the search term or not.
2. Look at the elasticsearch query logs to see what is happening in both cases(when the issue happens vs after cluster restart logs)
3. Is it intermittent or happens always and after how much time it again comes after cluster restart.

Comment: 1. yeah, that's the problem, there are no hits, but it still shows a high amount. I tried index-by-index, and a lot of them are problematic...

2. we have only slow queries logs, all the others are disable because too many queries...

3. it happens some time after the restart, haven't find a pattern yet.

Comment: @caarlos0 when you say, many indices are problematic, what exactly is the problem, do they contain your search term or what?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, was moving to another state... No, when the problem happens, doesn't matter the search terms, it always gives the same hit count (even when nothing is found)...

Comment: @caarlos0 thanks for your update, this is really strange would suggest you to open a bug on elastic or ask this on https://discuss.elastic.co/

Comment: already asked on discuss, guess I'll try opening an issue, but since its an old version, I doubt they'll fix it :/ https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cluster-eventually-starts-giving-absurdly-wrong-counts-on-search/252096/2

Comment: @caarlos0 yeah for the old version they wont fix it

Comment: thanks for the help anyway, will mark this as the answer so you get the points :)